# Browser splits up <p> and nested <code> blocks that contain nested <p> blocks. Why?

Tags: html, browser, html-parsing

You can see my problem in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rW6ah/).

I tried using`code` tags to distinguish special content, but this quickly backfired on me (as you can see in the above link).  When I use Firebug to look at the content, this:

```
<p>
    This is a sample paragraph with a code block:
    <code>
        <p> Some line of code </p>
        <p> Another line of code </p>
    </code>
</p>
```

has turned into this:

```
<p>
    This is a sample paragraph with a code block:
    <code> </code>
</p>
<p>
    <code> Some line of code </code>
</p>
<code>
    <p> Another line of code </p>
</code>
```

Now, this can be solved by changing `<code>` to `<div class="code">` (as seen in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y2Duu/)), but **why** did the browser do this in the first place, and why did it do it *only* to the first section in each paragraph?

Firefox, Opera, Chrome, Internet Explorer, Safari - all of them do this, but I'd really like to know why.  Does it happen with `code` only, or will it do this with other tags? And why would browsers move tags around like that?

Comment: For what it's worth, if you want to format code blocks, use `<pre><code>...</code></pre>` per code block.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

HTML places certain restrictions on which elements can be nested in which other elements. Sometimes browsers will happily construct a nonsensical DOM out of certain nesting scenarios, such as a `<div>` directly in a `<ul>`. Other times, they absolutely can't because of other written or unwritten parsing rules, such as `<p>` elements never containing any other block elements, not even other `<p>` elements (this is [implied by the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1)), so they have to work around it by changing the DOM to something that they *can* work with, resulting in the behavior you observe.

Because you cannot nest `<p>` elements within one another at all, what's happening here is that this element:

```
    <p> Some line of code </p>
```

is causing this other element to be terminated:

```
<p>
    This is a sample paragraph with a code block:
    <code>
```

Since there's an empty `<code>` tag in there, it's closed, and the containing `<p>` closed as well, because a subsequent `<p>` start tag will automatically close a preceding `<p>` start tag:

```
<p>
    This is a sample paragraph with a code block:
    <code> </code>
</p>
```

At this point a browser has to deal with the fact that the `<code>` and `<p>` tags are now effectively in the wrong order, but still nested. To compensate for the restructuring of the first "outer" `<p>` element, and the fact that there was going to be a `<code>` tag before the second "inner" `<p>`, it inserts `<code>` tags into the second `<p>`, turning its contents into code:

```
<p>
    <code> Some line of code </code>
</p>
```

Since browsers do seem to allow `<p>` within `<code>` for whatever reason (note that at this point the `<code>` is still not yet *explicitly terminated* with a `</code>`), the browser builds the rest of the DOM as follows, before continuing on its way:

```
<code>
    <p> Another line of code </p>
</code>
```

This is probably consistent across browsers for legacy and cross-browser compatibility reasons; some of these legacy parsing rules have been [retconned into sections of the HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tokenization.html#tree-construction) as well. Unfortunately, I'm not a browser implementer so I can't list out all possible scenarios; on the other hand, it's unwise to rely on such details considering the markup you're writing is invalid in the first place.

And, finally, [today's highly relevant xkcd](https://xkcd.com/1144) (of course):

[image: Tags]

Comment: why does this only happen to the first code block in each paragraph?

Comment: Who down voted this and why?  It's a perfectly sensible answer.

Comment: @Sparky672: I had originally said that browsers can't place `<p>` inside `<code>`, then I quickly realised how very wrong I was and proceeded to edit it to death.

Comment: @Sparky672 I guess because he edited the answer later, but this does make sense, check out the validator using direct input, use the markup from this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rW6ah/1/ and validate it here http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Comment: Short answer is "validate your HTML" or expect un-expected results,  but I like the detailed analysis here.

Comment: By the way, whoever that is, you may remove your downvote now. I've freed the voting lock with a nice big edit.

Comment: @Sparky672: Thanks, I was just getting to that :)

Comment: I don't know why someone downvoted this - it's a great answer!  It seems like the problem isn't having a `p` inside a `code`, but having `p` inside `code` inside `p`.  Sounds weird, but makes sense

Comment: @cegfault: Also a great question, which I'm starting to feel bad about collecting all the upvotes just for answering ([questions need votes too!](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/vote-for-this-question-or-the-kitten-gets-it)) ;)

Comment: @BoltClock: lol, thanks, but it's probably a good thing for answers to get more upvotes than questions ;)